# using ng-model with dynamically generated HTML form

Tags: angularjs, json2html

I have a JSON object that I am converting to HTML using json2html library. This HTML form has a username and password field. I need to pass the values of username and password entered to the backend for authentication. This form was working absolutely fine when the HTML was static, since now, HTML is generated dynamically ng-model for text fields is not working at all. Any help in eliminating this issue would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you, please hit the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Thanks, your reply was very helpful, I have generated the form using ng-repeat and by changing the attributes in the HTML element according to the values that I get from JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$compile`. Angular does not know about the html you just dumped onto the page (unless you did with Angular templating). You need to register the new dom with Angular and a specific scope.

Something like this:

```
$('#container').append($compile($(HTMLString)));
```

#### Learn all about it -> [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

---

However I would recommend not adding the html outside of Angular. You can do so a number of ways including using `$templateCache`.

```
$templateCache.put('myForm', HTMLString);
```

then

#### Learn all about it -> [$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache), [ngInclude](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

---

You could also write a directive, or even not dynamically make HTML, but rather attach the parsed JSON directly to `$scope` and do a clever `ng-repeat`.